# How to plot multiple lines in radar chart using split in plotly

Tags: r, plotly

I have tried using split trace with scatterpolar and it seems to partly work but can't get it to plot the values for all 10 variables. So I want each row (identified by "ean") be plotted as its own line using the values from X1 to X10.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(vroom)
library(plotly)

types <- rep(times = 10, list(
  col_integer(f = stats::runif,
              min = 1,
              max = 5)))

products = bind_cols(
  tibble(ean = sample.int(1e9, 25)),
  tibble(kategori = sample(c("kat1", "kat2", "kat3"), 25, replace = TRUE)),
  gen_tbl(25, 10, col_types = types)
  )

plot_ly(
    products,
    type = 'scatterpolar',
    mode = "lines+markers",
    r = ~X1,
    theta = ~"X1",
    split = ~ean
  )
```

How can I get plotly to plot all variables in the radarchart (X1-X10)? Usually I would select the columns with X1:X10 but I can't do that here (I think it has to do with that ~ is used to select variable here).

So I want the result to look something like this (but I only show lines and not filled polygons and I would have more products). So in the end 25 products is a lot but I am connecting it so that the user can select the diagrams it wants to show.

[image: plotly radar chart with multiple items]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. `object 'types' not found`

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that it was missing. Types variable is now added.

Comment: Great, thanks for the update. Please let me know if my answers meets your expectations. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In plotly it's convenient to use data in long format - see `?gather`.

Please check the following:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(vroom)
library(plotly)

types <- rep(times = 10, list(
  col_integer(f = stats::runif,
              min = 1,
              max = 5)))

products = bind_cols(
  tibble(ean = sample.int(1e9, 25)),
  tibble(kategori = sample(c("kat1", "kat2", "kat3"), 25, replace = TRUE)),
  gen_tbl(25, 10, col_types = types)
)

products_long <- gather(products, "key", "value", -ean, -kategori)

plot_ly(
  products_long,
  type = 'scatterpolar',
  mode = "lines+markers",
  r = ~value,
  theta = ~key,
  split = ~ean
)
```

[image: result]